# Javascript element.style.display = 'none' not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got the following dynamically built tree structure

```
<ul>
    <li class="parent" data-mapping-id="1">Node 1 <span>(filter on node 1)</span>
        <ul>
            <li class="parent" data-mapping-id="2">Node 1.1 <span>(filter on node 1.1</span>
                <ul>
                    <li class="parent" data-mapping-id="3">Node 1.1.1 <span>(filter on node 1.1.1</span>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="leaf">Node 1.1.1.1</li>
                            <li class="leaf">Node 1.1.1.2</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="parent" data-mapping-id="4">Node 1.1.2 <span>(filter on node 1.1.2</span>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="leaf">Node 1.1.2.1</li>
                            <li class="leaf">Node 1.1.2.2</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="parent" data-mapping-id="5">Node 1.2 <span>(filter on node 1.2</span>
                <ul>
                    <li class="parent" data-mapping-id="6">Node 1.2.1 <span>(filter on node 1.2.1</span>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="leaf">Node 1.2.1.1</li>
                            <li class="leaf">Node 1.2.1.2</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="parent" data-mapping-id="7">Node 1.2.2 <span>(filter on node 1.2.2</span>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="leaf">Node 1.2.2.1</li>
                            <li class="leaf">Node 1.2.2.2</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="parent" data-mapping-id="8">Node 1.3 <span>(filter on node 1.3</span>
                <ul>
                    <li class="parent" data-mapping-id="9">Node 1.3.1 <span>(filter on node 1.3.1</span>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="leaf">Node 1.3.1.1</li>
                            <li class="leaf">Node 1.3.1.2</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="parent" data-mapping-id="10">Node 1.3.2 <span>(filter on node 1.3.2</span>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="leaf">Node 1.3.2.1</li>
                            <li class="leaf">Node 1.3.2.2</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="parent" data-mapping-id="11">Node 2 <span>(filter on node 2)</span>
        <ul>
            <li class="parent" data-mapping-id="12">Node 2.1 <span>(filter on node 2.1</span>
                <ul>
                    <li class="parent" data-mapping-id="13">Node 2.1.1 <span>(filter on node 2.1.1</span>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="leaf">Node 2.1.1.1</li>
                            <li class="leaf">Node 2.1.1.2</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="parent" data-mapping-id="14">Node 2.1.2 <span>(filter on node 2.1.2</span>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="leaf">Node 2.1.2.1</li>
                            <li class="leaf">Node 2.1.2.2</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The `data-mapping-id` value is simply their ID from the database.

Which ends up looking like this

```
Node 1 (filter on node 1)
    Node 1.1 (filter on node 1.1)
        Node 1.1.1 (filter on node 1.1.1)
            Node 1.1.1.1
            Node 1.1.1.2
        Node 1.1.2 (filter on node 1.1.2)
            Node 1.1.2.1
            Node 1.1.2.2
    Node 1.2 (filter on node 1.2)
        Node 1.2.1 (filter on node 1.2.1)
            Node 1.2.1.1
            Node 1.2.1.2
        Node 1.2.2 (filter on node 1.2.2)
            Node 1.2.2.1
            Node 1.2.2.2
    Node 1.3 (filter on node 1.3)
        Node 1.3.1 (filter on node 1.3.1)
            Node 1.3.1.1
            Node 1.3.1.2
        Node 1.3.2 (filter on node 1.3.2)
            Node 1.3.2.1
            Node 1.3.2.2
...
```

By default only the root parents are visible (Node 1, Node 2, etc) but they can be opened/closed by clicking. The "filter on ..." `span`s are also clickable. For example, when a user clicks the "filter on node 1.1.1" span, the resulting HTML structure should be this

```
Node 1
    Node 1.1
        Node 1.1.1
            Node 1.1.1.1
            Node 1.1.1.2
```

In other words, all the direct parents of the clicked element should be shown, along with the direct children. If Node 1.1 is clicked, it should look like

```
Node 1
    Node 1.1
        Node 1.1.1
        Node 1.1.2
```

I've managed to get this working with a pretty ugly jquery function;

```
static hideChildren(element)
{
    // Gets the data-mapping-id from the clicked LI parent
    const id = element.getAttribute('data-mapping-id');
    // Uses that ID to get a jquery object
    element = $(`[data-mapping-id=${id}]`);
    // Ignore the direct children, but instead find all LI elements
    // belonging to the grandchildren of the clicked element
    element.children().children().find('li').toggle();
}
```

We want to move to 100% vanilla Javascript though, and as this is the last function using jquery in this class I'd like to convert it to vanilla Javascript as well. I tried the following function

```
static hideChildren(element)
{
    // Get the direct children of clicked element
    const children = [...element.children];
    children.forEach((child) => {
        // Ignore the SPAN tag
        if (child.tagName === 'UL') {
            // Get the grandchildren of clicked element
            const grandChildren = [...child.children];
            grandChildren.forEach((grandChild) => {
                // For each grandchild, find all child LI tags
                const lis = [...grandChild.querySelectorAll('li')];
                lis.forEach((li) => {
                    // For each found LI, set the 'display' value to 'none'
                    li.style.display = "none";
                });
            });
        }
    });
}
```

However, literally nothing happens. When I `console.log(li.style.display)` I do get `none` as a result, but the `LI`s are still displayed.

I've made a quick [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/07fdn19q/1/), which weirdly does exactly what I want it to do, but it doesn't work in my actual problem.

If the vanilla Javascript way doesn't work, I'd also gladly accept a better jquery alternative.

Comment: Why can't you use [`jsTree`](https://www.jstree.com/demo/) ?

Comment: I tried it, along with other packages, but I couldn't get them to work with Webpack Encore.